# How to use index of the DF in formula

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have formula:

```
df.loc[df.index].values.mean()
```

And DF, as: 
[image]

But I receive one value for all hours
[image]

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: don't you want `df.mean(axis=1)`? what you're doing is calling the `numpy` array `mean` which is not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want

```
df.mean(axis=1)
```

What you tried is called the [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) which by default returns the mean for the entire array

Example:

```
In[40]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[40]: 
          a         b         c
0 -0.220213 -0.437084 -1.566243
1 -1.004000 -1.458970  0.422262
2  2.193907 -1.234512  1.669380
3  1.813519 -0.070146  0.568940
4 -0.819410 -1.553415  0.071968

In[41]:
df.mean(axis=1)

Out[41]: 
0   -0.741180
1   -0.680236
2    0.876258
3    0.770771
4   -0.766952
dtype: float64
```

compare with what you did:

```
In[42]:
df.values.mean()

Out[42]: -0.10826778713282653
```

Also `df.loc[df.index]` is redundant as this is the same as just calling `df`

Comment: You mean, that I was receiving mean of the all df, instead of one row. Thank you

Comment: Yep, `.values` returns a numpy array, you then called the numpy version of `mean`. Also word of advice, post raw text for your data rather than a link to an image, also you should show the desired output